# MultiThreaded Depth Search C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, indexing, depth-first-search

I have built a program to index of all the files in my hardrive using a Depth Search; it worked. When I decided to try and make it multithreaded it threw **"terminate called recursively"** after 160 files. I am quite new to multithreading and I am not sure as to what is causing the problem or how to fix it.

```
void searsch(string location){
   vector<string> file = vector<string>();
   ofstream fileloc;
   fileloc.open("file_location.txt", std::ios::app);
   if((int)counter++%10000==0){cout<<location<<endl;}
   file=getdir(location);
   if(file.size()&&file.at(0)!=","){
       vector<thread> z;
       for(int i=0;i<file.size();i++)
       {
           if(file.at(i)=="."||file.at(i)==".."){continue;}
           z.push_back(thread(searsch,location+'\\'+file.at(i)));
       }
       for(int i=0;i<z.size();i++){
           z.at(i).join();
       }
   }
   else{
        ifstream is;
        is.open (location.c_str(), ios::binary );
        is.seekg (0, ios::end);
        fileloc<<location<<">"<<is.tellg()<<"\n";
        is.close();
   }
   return;
```

}

Comment: 1) you are using a global counter variable, I hope you made it atomic. It does not explain the crash though. 2) writing to a file from multiple threads this way is... scary 3) use a debugger you'll get a stacktrace and know where does the exception come from.

Comment: Because if thread1 writes "abcd" while thread2 writes "efgh" you can get "efabgchd" as a possible output in the file.

Comment: Oh, I understand. It doesn't do that before the error is called.